# Would an impeachment process automatically end with the end of a president's term?

Tags: united-states, impeachment

Currently, it is being considered to impeach president Trump with less than two weeks of his term remaining. To me, it does not appear to be  very plausible that such a process could be completed in such a short time-span. Does that mean that the idea behind such plans is "well, we cannot succeed, but we also cannot just sit here and do nothing", i.e., just symbolical? Or would an impeachment process possibly be continued beyond the duration of the term? While this could no longer have the effect of "firing" the president, it might have other effects such as disallowing later re-election (though presumably not denial of other benefits for ex-presidents even if they would be denied in case of a mid-term impeachment?)

Comment: Remember that impeachment is only the start of the process.  (And according to news reports, could take place before noon on January 20th.)  The trial by the Senate takes place later.  The point of such a trial (other than just expressing disapproval) would be to prevent Trump from ever holding office, or trying to run for office, again.